# POST error with Markdown in Jekyll for Github Page

Tags: php, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to implement a simple form in my Github page to learn how to use POST in html forms. The code I am using right now contains:

2014-07-05-post1.markdown:

```
<form action="/scripts/1.php" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

1.php:

```
<html>
<body>

 Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
 Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

However this returns an error:
   [image: Error]

How do you correctly use POST requests in Markdown and Jekyll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't.

Jekyll in the end generates just a static site, i.e. a bunch of HTML and CSS files. The server does nothing but serving those files, the server doesn't do any processing. But when you do a [HTTP POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29), you send data to the server and it would have to do something with the data (e.g. saving it to a database or sending an email).

So your form is correct but there's nothing on the server-side that can receive it. However, you could send the form data to a [third-party server](http://getsimpleform.com/) or use a PHP or node.js server for that.

Comment: Thanks getsimpleform seems like the way to go.